# What is a vectorized way to create multiple powers of a NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a NumPy array:

```
arr = [[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]
```

I want to create a new array that contains powers of `arr` up to a power `order`:

```
# arr_new = [arr^0, arr^1, arr^2, arr^3,...arr^order]
arr_new = [[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 8],
           [1, 1, 3, 4, 9, 16, 27, 64]]
```

My current approach uses `for` loops:

```
# Pre-allocate an array for powers
arr = np.array([[1, 2],[3,4]])
order = 3
rows, cols = arr.shape
arr_new = np.zeros((rows, (order+1) * cols))

# Iterate over each exponent
for i in range(order + 1):
    arr_new[:, (i * cols) : (i + 1) * cols] = arr**i
print(arr_new)
```

Is there a faster (i.e. vectorized) approach to creating powers of an array?

---

#### Benchmarking

Thanks to @hpaulj and @Divakar and @Paul Panzer for the answers. I benchmarked the loop-based and broadcasting-based operations on the following test arrays.

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2],
                [3,4]])
order = 3

arrLarge = np.random.randint(0, 10, (100, 100))  # 100 x 100 array
orderLarge = 10
```

The `loop_based` function is:

```
def loop_based(arr, order):
    # pre-allocate an array for powers
    rows, cols = arr.shape
    arr_new = np.zeros((rows, (order+1) * cols))
    # iterate over each exponent
    for i in range(order + 1):
        arr_new[:, (i * cols) : (i + 1) * cols] = arr**i
    return arr_new
```

The `broadcast_based` function using `hstack` is:

```
def broadcast_based_hstack(arr, order):
    # Create a 3D exponent array for a 2D input array to force broadcasting
    powers = np.arange(order + 1)[:, None, None]
    # Generate values (third axis contains array at various powers)
    exponentiated = arr ** powers
    # Reshape and return array
    return np.hstack(exponentiated)   # <== using hstack function
```

The `broadcast_based` function using `reshape` is:

```
def broadcast_based_reshape(arr, order):
    # Create a 3D exponent array for a 2D input array to force broadcasting
    powers = np.arange(order + 1)[:, None]
    # Generate values (3-rd axis contains array at various powers)
    exponentiated = arr[:, None] ** powers
    # reshape and return array
    return exponentiated.reshape(arr.shape[0], -1)  # <== using reshape function
```

The `broadcast_based` function using cumulative product `cumprod` and `reshape`:

```
def broadcast_cumprod_reshape(arr, order):
    rows, cols = arr.shape
    # Create 3D empty array where the middle dimension is
    # the array at powers 0 through order
    out = np.empty((rows, order + 1, cols), dtype=arr.dtype)
    out[:, 0, :] = 1   # 0th power is always 1
    a = np.broadcast_to(arr[:, None], (rows, order, cols))
    # Cumulatively multiply arrays so each multiplication produces the next order
    np.cumprod(a, axis=1, out=out[:,1:,:])
    return out.reshape(rows, -1)
```

On Jupyter notebook, I used the `timeit` command and got these results:

**Small arrays (2x2)**:

```
%timeit -n 100000 loop_based(arr, order)
7.41 µs ± 174 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit -n 100000 broadcast_based_hstack(arr, order)
10.1 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit -n 100000 broadcast_based_reshape(arr, order)
3.31 µs ± 61.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit -n 100000 broadcast_cumprod_reshape(arr, order)
11 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Large arrays (100x100)**:

```
%timeit -n 1000 loop_based(arrLarge, orderLarge)
261 µs ± 5.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000 broadcast_based_hstack(arrLarge, orderLarge)
225 µs ± 4.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000 broadcast_based_reshape(arrLarge, orderLarge)
223 µs ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit -n 1000 broadcast_cumprod_reshape(arrLarge, orderLarge)
157 µs ± 1.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

#### Conclusions:

It seems that the broadcast based approach using `reshape` is faster for smaller arrays. However, for large arrays, the `cumprod` approach scales better and is faster.

Comment: That `broadcast_based_reshape` looks wrong. The order of extending arrays is different. Follow my post for the exact code.

Comment: I tried both ways with `reshape`- with and without extending the input array `arr`. It seems their run times are within the margin of error from each other. I understand why a higher dimensional array of exponents was made (`np.arange(order+1)[:,None]`) to force broadcasting. I do not know why you also used `arr[:, None]`.

Comment: Extending both arrays is needed to use reshape later on, the idea being to make the ordering as needed in the output. I was talking more about the correctness of the output and not the performance there.

Comment: Thanks - I realized my error in implementing your approach. Fixed (I think).

Comment: Yup, looks good now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend arrays to higher dims and let [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) do its *magic* with some help from `reshaping` -

```
In [16]: arr = np.array([[1, 2],[3,4]])

In [17]: order = 3

In [18]: (arr[:,None]**np.arange(order+1)[:,None]).reshape(arr.shape[0],-1)
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  2,  1,  4,  1,  8],
       [ 1,  1,  3,  4,  9, 16, 27, 64]])
```

Note that `arr[:,None]` is essentially `arr[:,None,:]`, but we can skip the trailing ellipsis for brevity.

Timings on a bigger dataset -

```
In [40]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: arr = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,100))
    ...: order = 10

# @hpaulj's soln with broadcasting and stacking
In [41]: %timeit np.hstack(arr **np.arange(order+1)[:,None,None])
1000 loops, best of 3: 734 µs per loop

In [42]: %timeit (arr[:,None]**np.arange(order+1)[:,None]).reshape(arr.shape[0],-1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 401 µs per loop
```

That reshaping part is practically free and that's where we gain performance here alongwith the broadcasting part of course, as seen in the breakdown below -

```
In [52]: %timeit (arr[:,None]**np.arange(order+1)[:,None])
1000 loops, best of 3: 390 µs per loop

In [53]: %timeit (arr[:,None]**np.arange(order+1)[:,None]).reshape(arr.shape[0],-1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 401 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 7):

Use broadcasting to generate the values, and reshape or rearrange the values as desired:

```
In [34]: arr **np.arange(4)[:,None,None]
Out[34]: 
array([[[ 1,  1],
        [ 1,  1]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 1,  4],
        [ 9, 16]],

       [[ 1,  8],
        [27, 64]]])
In [35]: np.hstack(_)
Out[35]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  2,  1,  4,  1,  8],
       [ 1,  1,  3,  4,  9, 16, 27, 64]])
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using cumulative multiplication which scales better than power based approaches, especially if the input array is of `float` dtype:

```
import numpy as np

def f_mult(a, k):
    m, n = a.shape
    out = np.empty((m, k, n), dtype=a.dtype)
    out[:, 0, :] = 1
    a = np.broadcast_to(a[:, None], (m, k-1, n))
    a.cumprod(axis=1, out=out[:, 1:])
    return out.reshape(m, -1)
```

Timings:

```
int up to power 9
divakar: 0.4342731796205044 ms
hpaulj:  0.794165057130158 ms
pp:      0.20520629966631532 ms
float up to power 39
divakar: 29.056487752124667 ms
hpaulj:  31.773792404681444 ms
pp:      1.0329263447783887 ms
```

Code for timings, thks @Divakar:

```
def f_divakar(a, k):
    return (a[:,None]**np.arange(k)[:,None]).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)

def f_hpaulj(a, k):
    return np.hstack(a**np.arange(k)[:,None,None])


from timeit import timeit

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,100))
k = 10
print('int up to power 9')
print('divakar:', timeit(lambda: f_divakar(a, k), number=1000), 'ms')
print('hpaulj: ', timeit(lambda: f_hpaulj(a, k), number=1000), 'ms')
print('pp:     ', timeit(lambda: f_mult(a, k), number=1000), 'ms')

a = np.random.uniform(0.5,2.0,(100,100))
k = 40
print('float up to power 39')
print('divakar:', timeit(lambda: f_divakar(a, k), number=1000), 'ms')
print('hpaulj: ', timeit(lambda: f_hpaulj(a, k), number=1000), 'ms')
print('pp:     ', timeit(lambda: f_mult(a, k), number=1000), 'ms')
```

Comment: Hmm - I'm getting different results when I implement the `cumprod` approach. My implementation of your answer is added to my benchmarking edit.

Comment: @hazrmad, as I said it _scales_ better, i.e. it will be faster as soon as the problem size is large enough. Your test example is so small that you are mostly measuring overheads.

Comment: Thanks! I ran tests with 100x100 arrays and indeed your approach was faster. I'll add a note.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a [Vandermonde matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html) with a reshape, so it is probably best to use `numpy.vander` to make it, and let someone else take care of the best algorithm.

This way your code is just:

```
np.vander(arr.ravel(), order).reshape((arr.shape[0], -1))
```

That said, it seems like they use something like Paul Panzer's cumprod method [under the hood](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py#L443-L530) so it should scale well.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how does one even go about looking for such a function without knowing exactly what to look for.

Comment: In my case, I came across it years ago learning about Reed Solomon coding. I forgot everything else about that stuff, but the Vandermonde matrix keeps popping up!